# Print certain columns with certain values from CSV file using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to currently using the Iris classification dataset with Python and Pandas to do some data analysis. I'm trying to print all the petal-length values that are greater than 1.7 and where the data species is Setosa but I'm having a problem.

I keep getting this error:

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Here is my code:

```
iris = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\username\Downloads\iris.csv")
for row in iris:
    if iris["species"] == "setosa":
         if iris["petal_width"] > 1.7:
            print(iris["petal_width"])
```

Any help or suggestions you can give me I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: `print(iris.loc[(iris["species"] == "setosa") & (iris["petal_width"] > 1.7),"petal_width"])`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)

Answer (score 1):

```
print(iris.query("petal_length>1.7 & species=='setosa'")['petal_length'])
```

Answer (score -1):

From Anurag's comment

```
print(iris.loc[(iris["species"] == "setosa") & (iris["petal_width"] > 1.7),"petal_width"])
```